# Error "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

Tags: python, loops, directory

I get error. The reason i get the error is when there are no more files with .mp4 in directory. My goal is for it start when there is a .mp4 file in the directory, but having trouble figuring out loops.

```
File "C:\PUBG\nn.py", line 8, in <module>
    newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), ke
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

---

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2

os.chdir('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/')

newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime)

os.replace((newest), 'replay.mp4')

if newest != max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/replay.mp4')

    def rescale_frame(frame, percent=25):
        width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent/ 100)
        height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

    while True:
        ret ,frame = cap.read()
        if type(frame) == type(None):
            break
        frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
        cv2.imshow('frame25',frame25)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
os.remove('replay.mp4')
```

Comment: If there are no files, there's no newest file.

Comment: You say "My goal is for it start when there is a .mp4 file in the directory". Are you trying to *wait* for such a file to exist, or have the script automatically *trigger* when such a file is created, or when such a file is fully written, or what? What's the context; how and why is this script being run when there is no input for it?

Comment: i prefer to automatically trier when created

Comment: If you want to trigger automatically from within your program, you need to each use the [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx`) API (e.g., via `pywin32`)—search `FindFirstChangeNotification python` and you should get lots of usable examples), or use a third-party wrapper from PyPI that offers portable behavior across Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: If that sounds hard (but it really isn't that hard), you may want to instead find a helper tool that watches for directory changes and just runs a new instance of your script with the new file(s) in your `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the list is empty first:

```
times = [os.path.getctime(p) for p in glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4')]
if not times or newest != max(times): # you might want different logic here...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.ended up using watchdog

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = 'C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/'

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()


        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':

            os.chdir('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/')

            newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime)

            os.replace((newest), 'replay.mp4')


            cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/replay.mp4')

            def rescale_frame(frame, percent=25):
                width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent/ 100)
                height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
                dim = (width, height)
                return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

            while True:
                ret ,frame = cap.read()
                if type(frame) == type(None):
                    break
                frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
                cv2.imshow('frame25',frame25)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```